# Running an abaqus python script via batch file?

Tags: python, batch-file, abaqus

I have written a python script(or function) that get some argument and need to run by abaqus and I want to do this by a batch file. I am new in batch file and do not know how i can run a python script in different path by abaqus. For example, assume that the python code path is `D:\pythonscript\test.py`.

Comment: showing whats actually in your script might be enlightening

Comment: This is a python code that get a couple of variables and do some activities in abaqus and that is just it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, you will have to update your path to Abaqus as i would guess your version is more recent.

```
"C:\Abaqus\6.10-EF2\exec\abq610ef2.exe" cae script=D:\pythonscript\test.py %*
```

Comment: It does not work. is there any problem if I have space between my script path?

Comment: If you open cae does the script work if you select file - run script? Also did you set the abaqus path to the one you are using? When you run the batch file does cmd open and are any messages shown. Let me know how you get on

Comment: Yes It Works properly when i run it by run script option in Abaqus GUI. For getting the path that abaqus has been installed I make right click on ABAQUS icon on desktop and then 'open file location'. But I just see abq6134.bat and not any .exe file in this path and when I search for Abaqus CAE.exe and I find its path, this path is very different in comparison the path you had mentioned and I think this should not be so. Can I insert the abq6134.bat path instead Abaqus CAE.exe?

Comment: if you open that batch file in notepad it should contain something like this "@echo off
"C:\Abaqus\6.13-4\code\bin\abq6131.exe" %*" - this is the path you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help, It worked.but there was a point.When we have space between our path(here .py file path), We have to put the path between double quotes. Do you know If I want to exit from abaqus how I have to do it?

Comment: If you include "nogui" in your batch file. This will complete the script without opening abaqus cae. 
for example: - "C:\Abaqus\6.10-EF2\exec\abq610ef2.exe" cae nogui script=D:\pythonscript\test.py %*

Comment: This only works for script. Do you know if I would like to get some arguments as inputs of the .py file, how I have to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass infromation to your python script from a batch file, you need `sys`

```
import sys
inodb = openOdb(path=str(sys.argv[1])) #for example
```

`argv` is a list of arguments sent to the python script.  `argv[0]` is the name and path of the script itself, and every thing after is separated by spaces.

Then in your batch file (for example):

```
for %%f in (.\*.odb) do (
    abaqus python D:\pythonscript\test.py %%f
)
```

This is for *stand alone* scripts.  You'll have to modify it a bit for `cae` scripts, but I don't use them anymore (means I need a license, which are in short supply) so I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line in the .bat file to have Abaqus run a python script:

```
start abaqus cae script="C:<location_of_.py_script>\<scriptname>.py"
```

I would recommend to have the arguments for the python script collected in the python script itself, either using the input() function or by reading an input file somewhere else. You can specify within the python script where to find the file containing the arguments.

Comment: You might be right, I don't claim to be an expert in programming. However I've learned that programming requires a strict syntax and I was unable to figure out what the " %* " mark stands for. I also tried to find an abaqus.exe file or the one mentioned above but I was unable to find an executable for abaqus. I do have a SIMULIA folder with many subfolders which I haven't searched thoroughly and the search option gave me tons of .exe files. Just found out the above command worked for me and hoped it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
abaqus cae noGUI="Full path to your code"
```

If you want to see the simulation, replace "noGUI" with "script"